# For loop to call API function and wait for it

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have my data going into a API in a loop as below. How can I ensure that the next iteration is called when the first is finished? Image my API takes a second for each element

```
saveMyData(){
  this.elements.forEach(element => {
    CALL_MY_API.read(element)
    .then(response =>  {
        // comes here in 1 second
        // do something with response
    }
    .catch(error => {
       this.showError(error)
    })
 })
}
```

Comment: Your forEach loop should already be doing that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the `read` function is asynchronous, all the requests will be made before the first API call is finished.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The foreach loop generates the promise, but does not wait until it is finished
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48014050/wait-promise-inside-for-loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: You should use async await

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This starts a bunch of asynchronous operations in parallel. I assume that's not what you want, and you want to wait for one to actually finish before starting the next one.

It's easiest if you can use `async`/`await` syntax:

```
async saveMyData() {
  for (const element of this.elements) {
    try {
      const response = await CALL_MY_API.read(element)
      // do something with response
    } catch (error) {
      this.showError(error)
    }
  }
}
```

If you can't, you'll need to chain the promises manually:

```
saveMyData() {
  // Start with an immediately resolved promise.
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve())
  // Add each element to the chain.
  this.elements.forEach(element => {
    promise = promise.then(() => {
      return CALL_MY_API.read(element)
        .then(response => {
          // do something with response
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.showError(error)
        })
    })
  })
}
```